Search for special characters in table not working properly
In my react app which is built using typescript and MUI I created the following component:


"use client";
import React, { useState, useCallback, useMemo } from "react";
import {
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableContainer,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  Paper,
  TableSortLabel,
  Box,
  useTheme as useMuiTheme,
  Typography,
} from "@mui/material";
import { Quote } from "@/types/Quote";

import DeleteForeverIcon from "@mui/icons-material/DeleteForever";
import EditIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Edit";
import DeleteQuoteDialog from "./DeleteQuoteDialog";
import SortOrder from "@/types/SortOrder";
import { getComparator, stableSort } from "@/utils/helpers";
import NewQuoteDialog from "./NewQuoteDialogue";
import Tooltip from "@mui/material/Tooltip";
import { formatPrice } from "@/commonHelpers";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { calculateQuoteHardwareCost } from "@/utils/costsCalculator";

interface QuoteTableProps {
  quotes: Quote[];
  searchText: string;
}

const QuoteTable: React.FC<QuoteTableProps> = ({ quotes, searchText }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [openDeleteDialog, setOpenDeleteDialog] = useState(false);
  const [openEditDialog, setOpenEditDialog] = useState(false);
  const [selectedQuote, setSelectedQuote] = useState<Quote>({
    id: "",
    quoteNr: "",
    customer: "",
    projectType: "",
    createdAt: "",
    hardwareCosts: [],
    softwareCosts: [],
    estimation: 0,
  });
  const [order, setOrder] = useState<SortOrder>("asc");
  const [orderBy, setOrderBy] = useState<keyof Quote>("quoteNr");

  const handleRequestSort = useCallback(
    (property: keyof Quote) => {
      const isAsc = orderBy === property && order === "asc";
      setOrder(isAsc ? "desc" : "asc");
      setOrderBy(property);
    },
    [order, orderBy],
  );

  const handleRowClick = useCallback(
    (quoteId: string) => {
      router.push("/quotes/" + quoteId);
    },
    [router],
  );

  const handleDeleteRow = useCallback(
    (e: any, quote: Quote) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      setSelectedQuote(quote);
      setOpenDeleteDialog(true);
    },
    [setOpenDeleteDialog, setSelectedQuote],
  );

  const handleEditRow = useCallback(
    (e: any, quote: Quote) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      setSelectedQuote(quote);
      setOpenEditDialog(true);
    },
    [setOpenEditDialog, setSelectedQuote],
  );

  const handleCloseDeleteDialog = useCallback(() => {
    setOpenDeleteDialog(false);
  }, []);

  const handleCloseEditDialog = useCallback(() => {
    setOpenEditDialog(false);
  }, []);

  const calculateEstimation = useCallback((quote: Quote): number => {
    return calculateQuoteHardwareCost(quote.hardwareCosts);
  }, []);

  const quotesWithEstimation = useMemo(() => {
    return quotes.map((quote) => ({
      ...quote,
      estimation: calculateEstimation(quote),
    }));
  }, [quotes, calculateEstimation]);

  const filteredQuotes = useMemo(
    () =>
      quotesWithEstimation.filter((quote) =>
        Object.entries(quote).some(([key, value]) => {
          if (key === "estimation") {
            return formatPrice(value as number)
              .toLowerCase()
              .includes(searchText.toLowerCase());
          }
          return value
            .toString()
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(searchText.toLowerCase());
        }),
      ),
    [quotesWithEstimation, searchText],
  );

  const muiTheme = useMuiTheme();

  return (
    <>
      <TableContainer
        component={Paper}
        sx={{ maxHeight: "calc(100vh - 200px)" }}
      >
        <Table aria-label="quotes table" stickyHeader>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              {[
                { id: "quoteNr", label: "Quote nr." },
                { id: "customer", label: "Customer" },
                { id: "projectType", label: "Project type" },
                { id: "createdAt", label: "Date created" },
                { id: "estimation", label: "Estimation" },
              ].map((headCell) => (
                <TableCell
                  key={headCell.id}
                  sortDirection={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : false}
                  sx={{
                    typography: "h6",
                    bgcolor:
                      muiTheme.palette.mode === "dark" ? "#424242" : "#ececec",
                  }}
                >
                  <TableSortLabel
                    active={true}
                    direction={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : "asc"}
                    onClick={() =>
                      handleRequestSort(headCell.id as keyof Quote)
                    }
                  >
                    <Box
                      component="span"
                      sx={{ display: "inline-flex", alignItems: "center" }}
                    >
                      {headCell.label}
                    </Box>
                  </TableSortLabel>
                </TableCell>
              ))}
              <TableCell
                sx={{
                  typography: "h6",
                  bgcolor:
                    muiTheme.palette.mode === "dark" ? "#424242" : "#ececec",
                }}
              >
                Actions
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {filteredQuotes.length > 0 ? (
              stableSort(filteredQuotes, getComparator(order, orderBy)).map(
                (quote) => (
                  <TableRow
                    key={quote.id}
                    hover
                    onClick={() => handleRowClick(quote.id!)}
                    style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                  >
                    <TableCell>{quote.quoteNr}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{quote.customer}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{quote.projectType}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                      {quote.createdAt
                        ? new Date(quote.createdAt).toLocaleDateString("en-GB")
                        : ""}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                      <Typography component="span" sx={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>
                        {formatPrice(quote.estimation)}
                      </Typography>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                      <Tooltip title="Edit Quote" placement="left">
                        <EditIcon
                          color="primary"
                          style={{
                            cursor: "pointer",
                            marginRight: "10px",
                          }}
                          onClick={(e) => handleEditRow(e, quote)}
                        />
                      </Tooltip>
                      <Tooltip title="Delete Quote" placement="right">
                        <DeleteForeverIcon
                          color="error"
                          onClick={(e) => handleDeleteRow(e, quote)}
                        />
                      </Tooltip>
                    </TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                ),
              )
            ) : (
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell colSpan={6} align="center">
                  No quotes found.
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            )}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
      <DeleteQuoteDialog
        id={selectedQuote?.id}
        quoteNr={selectedQuote?.quoteNr}
        open={openDeleteDialog}
        onClose={handleCloseDeleteDialog}
        onDeleted={handleCloseDeleteDialog}
      />
      <NewQuoteDialog
        selectedQuote={selectedQuote}
        open={openEditDialog}
        action="EDIT"
        onClose={handleCloseEditDialog}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default QuoteTable;



The issue that I am facing is that in the search bar when I am searching for a row with special characters it is either not recognizing at all and showing all rows (no filtering) or recognizing it but not working properly. For example:
Let us say I have in the first row Quote Nr. 123 and in the second row Quote Nr. -756
If I just put a hyphen in the searchbar it should only show the second row however it is showing both rows. Another example would be let us say I have 2 rows Quote Nr. -123 and another row Quote Nr. 12-34 if I put -3 it should show the second row however it is showing both rows. What is the problem here ? How can I fix it ?

.includes return true or false

@ALFaizAhmed Thank you for your answer. But how should I fix it ?
